# Consuming HAL-based REST service with spring-hateoas

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-hateoas

I'm trying to consume a HAL-based REST service with the RestTemplate class.
The response body looks like this:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "school:teachers": [
      {
        "name": "Adams",
        "state": "CA",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/teachers/1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Barnes",
        "state": "FL",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/teachers/2"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Armstrong",
        "state": "GA",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/teachers/3"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "curies": [
      {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/docs/html5/{rel}.html",
        "name": "school",
        "templated": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The `Teacher` class looks like this:

```
public class Teacher {
    private String name;
    private String state;

    // getters and setters...
}
```

The return type of the REST service for GET method is `ResponseEntity<Resources<Resource<Component>>>`. Therefore my request in the client code looks like this:

```
...
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

Map<String, Object> dummy = new HashMap<>();
HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = getHttpEntity(); 

ResponseEntity<Resources<Resource<Teacher>>> response = restTemplate.exchange(url,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                httpEntity,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<Resources<Resource<Teacher>>>() {});

Resources<Resource<Teacher>> resources = response.getBody();
...
```

When i make the request with the response type `ParameterizedTypeReference` the content of the response is empty. When i do it with `String` i retrieve the content list.

How should i do the request to retrieve it with the response type `ParameterizedTypeReference` to map it directly in the POJO?

Comment: Your service returning `Resources<Resource<Teacher>>` seems highly questionable. If you control the code, consider changing it. That said, must you use `RestTemplate` on the client side? If not, [Traverson](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.23.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#client.traverson) is a much better choice because it is built for navigating HAL response, whereas `RestTemplate` isn't.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I don't control the server-side code, therefore i have to work with it. I never heard about Traverson, i have to look how to make a request.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar what is wrong with `Resources<Resource<Teacher>>`?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar have to ask the same question - Whats wrong with that response type? That's both legitimate and common. In particular why do you think this matters. The problem is about consuming JSON, surely? So the response 'type' on the server is of no concern.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely, you should go with Traverson

```
Traverson client = new Traverson(new URI("http://localhost:8080/api/"), 
         MediaTypes.HAL_JSON);
    Resources<Resource<Teacher>> teachers = client
        .follow("school:teachers")
        .toObject(new ResourcesType<Resource<Teacher>>(){});
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#client.traverson

Answer (score 2):

I tried a similar approach to what Vishnoo Rath. I am planning to build a common method to do this for all my resources.

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = 
                restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8081/rest/cars", HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);

        String data = response.getBody();
        //log.info(data);

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        JsonNode jsNode = om.readTree(data);
        String test = jsNode.at("/_embedded/cars").toString();
        //log.info(test);

        ArrayList<Car> cars = om.readValue(test, new TypeReference<List<Car>>() {
        });

        for (Car theCar : cars) {
            log.info(">>> " + theCar.getMake() + " " + theCar.getModel() + " " + theCar.getYear());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [Bowman](https://github.com/BlackPepperSoftware/bowman) to consume JSON+HAL resources in JAVA. This library greatly simplifies the consumption of resources comparing to RestTemplate as shown in [this article](https://hdpe.me/post/spring-data-rest-hal-client/).

Comment: Rather than linking to external URL, please add relevant code and explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced a similar problem. And the way I chose to work around it is :

```
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                "http://localhost:8080/payment/search/findByApprovalDate?approvalDate=2017-11-06", HttpMethod.GET,
                null, String.class);

        String data = response.getBody();

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        JsonNode jsNode = om.readTree(data);
        String test = jsNode.at("/_embedded/payment").toString();

        payments = om.readValue(test, new TypeReference<List<RHPayment>>() {
        });
```