# HAL-based REST service client using Traverson

Tags: java, rest, client, spring-hateoas

I am trying to write a Java program to consume the output from a REST-based web service I wrote utilizing the tutorials at spring.io.  When I run SpringBoot bootRun the JSON output is built nicely with embedded data and links, and looks like this:

```
 {
"_embedded": {
    "invoiceList": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "seqNum": 1,
            "fileId": null,
            "fileName": null,
            "invoiceNumber": "10080",
            "invoiceDate": "2018-06-18T05:00:00.000+0000",
            "invoiceTotal": 1000,
            "sourceLastModified": "2018-11-30T16:22:23.000+0000",
            "lastModified": "2018-11-30T16:22:23.000+0000",
            "validFrom": "2018-11-30T16:22:23.000+0000",
            "validTo": "9999-12-31T06:00:00.000+0000",
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8086/vadir/dental/invoices/4"
                },
                "invoices": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8086/vadir/dental/invoices"
                },
                "claims": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8086/vadir/dental/claims?invoice=10080"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "seqNum": 1,
            "fileId": null,
            "fileName": null,
            "invoiceNumber": "10080",
            "invoiceDate": "2018-06-18T05:00:00.000+0000",
            "invoiceTotal": 500,
            "sourceLastModified": "2018-11-30T16:22:23.000+0000",
            "lastModified": "2018-11-30T16:22:23.000+0000",
            "validFrom": "2018-11-30T16:22:23.000+0000",
            "validTo": "9999-12-31T06:00:00.000+0000",
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8086/vadir/dental/invoices/5"
                },
                "invoices": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8086/vadir/dental/invoices"
                },
                "claims": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8086/vadir/dental/claims?invoice=10080"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8086/vadir/dental/invoices/last"
    }
}
```

}

I have found the documentation for Traverson and the SO question at [Consuming HAL-based REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703962/consuming-hal-based-rest-service-with-spring-hateoas).  However, when I use

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<Resources<Resource<DentalInvoice>>> parameterizedTypeReference =
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<Resources<Resource<DentalInvoice>>> () {
        };
    Traverson traverson =
        new Traverson (new URI ("http://localhost:8086/vadir/dental/invoices/last"), MediaTypes.HAL_JSON);
    Resources<Resource<DentalInvoice>> invoiceResources = traverson
                                                    //.follow ((String) null)
                                                    .follow ("$._embedded.invoiceList")
                                                    .toObject (parameterizedTypeReference);
```

I get an error: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: [{"id":4,...

It looks like Traverson is expecting the content of the follow reference to be a link rather than an embedded object.  How can I get Traverson to parse the embedded object into a list of Resources of DentalInvoices?

Do I have to create a controller method that only outputs the links to the possible actions just so Traverson has a link to follow?